# Question about a lemma in Hungerford's undergraduate abstract algebra text concerning finite abelian group.

Tags: group-theory

I have some question regarding the theorem below in bold.  The materials is in Hungerford's undergraduate abstract algebra text 3rd edition, chapter 9, section 2.  The notations are as follows:

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $p$ be prime.  Let $G(p)=\{a\in G: |a|=p^n \text{ for some n}\geq 0 \}$ which is equivalent to $G(p)=\{a\in G: ap^n = 0 \text{ for some n}\geq 0 \}$

and the theorem:

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let $G$ be an abelian group and $a\in G$ an element of finite order.  Then $a=a_{1}+a_{2}+ \cdots+a_{t},$ with $a_{i}\in G(p_{i})$, where $p_{1},p_{2}, \ldots,p_{t}$ are the distinct positive primes that divide the order of $a$.

The example used in the Hungerford's text was $G=Z_{12}$, and $G(2)=\{0,3,6,9\}$, and $G(3)=\{0,4,8\}$

For the theorem above, if I pick $8\in Z_{12}$, then $|8|=3$ then $8=4+4$, $4\in G(3)$. Another example is if I choose, $11\in Z_{12}$, we have $|11|=12$ and $11=4+4+3$, $4\in G(3)$, $3\in G(2)$.

My question is:  where does the sum $a=a_{1}+a_{2}+ \cdots+a_{t},$ come from in the theory of finite abelian group.  What I mean is if we have a finite abelian group $G$, and any $a\in G$, with $|G|=n$. Then $n$ can be factor into product of primes.  How do these primes relate back to $a=a_{1}+a_{2}+ \cdots+a_{t}$ I tried looking through various other abstract algebra texts, but I was not able to find a satisfactory explanations.  Can someone give further explanations please.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is essentially a corollary of [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain). In more elementary language, just like how you can express $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a direct sum of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{R}$, you can express finite abelian groups as direct sums of finite collections of cyclic groups.

Comment: @William I only have basic knowledge of module theory. I am trying to figure out why and how the $a_i$s are there and related to the prime factorization of the order of the group $|G|$.

Comment: $8=G(3)+G(3)=4+4$ doesn't make any sense. The middle terms are *subsets*, not elements, of $G$. The only prime divisor of $|8|$ is $3$, so the theorem tells you that you can write $8$ as the sum of a **single** element of $G(3)$. And you can: $8=8$.

Comment: Your example with $11$ is likewise muddled (again you mix elements and subsets as if they were the same type of object; they are not), and you are not following what the theorem tells you anywa6.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I edit my post.  My bad, when I wrote the sum out, i wrote it out that way to help myself keeping track where the $a_{i}$s are coming from.

Comment: Did you not read the theorem? Did you not notice the word "distinct" right there when describing the primes? You can't just ignore that word.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I did read it.  I am not sure in the wording of the theorem if you can have more than one $a_{i}$ from a single $G(p_{i})$.

Comment: Then you did not read it carefully. The theorem's wording is extremely clear: exactly one summand for each distinct prime factor. That's why the indices match. Saying otherwise is, quite simply, an unreasonable or careless reading.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks for clarifying that.  I wasn't sure if "distinct" has to do with what you were referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the order of $a$ is $n$. We will proceed by induction with respect to the number of prime numbers that divide $n$. If that number is $0$,  there is nothing to prove, so we are happy.

Suppose that $n$ is divisible by at least one prime number. Then $n=p^rq$ with $p$ a prime number, $r$ a positive integer, and $q$ a positive integer not divisible by $p$. Since $p^r$ and $q$ are coprime, there are integers $u$ and $v$ such that $up^r+vq=1$. Let $b=vq\cdot a$ and $c=up^r\cdot a$. Since $p^r\cdot b=vp^rq\cdot a=0$, the order of $b$ divides $p^r$ and this $b$ is in $G(p)$.

On the other hand, the order of $c$ divides $q$, since $q\cdot c=up^rq\cdot a=0$, and it is therefore divisible by one prime less that the order $a$. The obvious inductive hypothesis then applies to $c$, and we see that $c\in G(p_1)+\cdots G(p_t)$ with $p_1,\dots,p_t$ dividing the order of $c$.

Now $$a=1\cdot a=(up^r+vq)\cdot a=up^r\cdot a+vq\cdot a=c+b\in  G(p_1)+\cdots G(p_t)+G(p),$$ and clearly $p_1,\dots,p_t$ and $p$ divide the order of $a$.

Comment: let me see if I can related it back to the theorem in details.  I will let you know if I am not clear in any details.  Thank you so very much for the detail write up.